# vba Autofilter and copy results to another sheet: i can't copy the right range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that filters information in sheet ANAF CONTURI (**criteria on column G3 and going down up to G10000**) and copies the results (from A3:F3 and going down) into sheet ANAF BANCI starting from C2:H2 and going down.

The problem: If I don't input any information in sheet ANAF CONTURI in **A3** it wont copy anything from that row (even if the criteria is a match and the rest of the cells from that row till F3 have data).

It would have been ok if it was doing this on cell B3 because if I don't have data on  cell B3 the rest of the row is irrelevant but it only takes cell A3 in consideration.

What is the solution ?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
' TRIAZA INFORMATIA INTRODUSA SI O INAINTEAZA SPRE PRELUCRARE IN ANAF BANCI

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Sheet8.Unprotect Password:="online07"
  Sheets("ANAF BANCI").Range("C2:H1000").ClearContents

  With Sheets("ANAF CONTURI") '<--| reference your sheet         
    With .Range("G2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column "A:G" range from row 1 down to column "A" last not empty row

      .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Da" ''<--| filter referenced range on its 7th column (i.e. column "G") with "Da" values
      If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 6).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ANAF BANCI").Range("C2")
    End With    

    If (Sheets("ANAF CONTURI").AutoFilterMode And Sheets("ANAF CONTURI").FilterMode) Or Sheets("ANAF CONTURI").FilterMode Then
      Sheets("ANAF CONTURI").ShowAllData
    End If
  End With

  Sheet8.Range("A3:F20000").Locked = False
  Sheet8.Protect Password:="online07"

  ' SortareAlaZ Macro
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("- - REZULTAT ANAF - -").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("- - REZULTAT ANAF - -").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range("O3:O16571"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
  With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("- - REZULTAT ANAF - -").AutoFilter.Sort
      .Header = xlYes
      .MatchCase = False
      .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
      .SortMethod = xlPinYin
      .Apply
  End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You wrote "If I don't input any information in sheet ANAF CONTURI in A3": do you mean column A is empty?

Comment: yes. i used another way in the end to do the same thing because i couldn't find the fix with that one :)

Comment: what column actually _always_ sets the data "length"?

Comment: im new to vba (one week old) but i think that was what was missing and probably by default took column A as reference? don;t know..

Comment: in OP's code `.Range("G2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))` statement takes column "A" (i.e. with column index `1`) as reference to get the last not used cell. If you know your "database" length is _always_ determined by column "B" data then just change that statement to `.Range("G2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))`

Comment: Thank you. I got to work on my vba skills. I had a project for work to do and it's almoast finished. I have only one more question that i don't know how to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way that works and does the same thing :

```
Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Dim filterRange As range
    Dim copyRange As range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ANAF CONTURI")
    Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ANAF BANCI")

    ' turn off any autofilters that are already set
    src.AutoFilterMode = False

    ' find the last row with data in column A
    lastRow = src.range("B" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' the range that we are auto-filtering (all columns)
    Set filterRange = src.range("A2:G" & lastRow)

    ' the range we want to copy (only columns we want to copy)
    ' in this case we are copying country from column A
    ' we set the range to start in row 2 to prevent copying the header
    Set copyRange = src.range("A3:F" & lastRow)

    ' filter range based on column B
    filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Da"

    ' copy the visible cells to our target range
    ' note that you can easily find the last populated row on this sheet
    ' if you don't want to over-write your previous results
    copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.range("C2")



          If (Sheets("ANAF CONTURI").AutoFilterMode And Sheets("ANAF CONTURI").FilterMode) Or Sheets("ANAF CONTURI").FilterMode Then
  Sheets("ANAF CONTURI").ShowAllData
  End If
```